# Vue js change and animate position of element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that needs to create a random dots.

```
<div>
 <span v-for="point in getPoints()" 
     class="dot" :style="calcPosition()"></span>
</div>

methods: {
  getPoints() {
    return _.range(0, 100);
  },
  calcPosition() {
    return {
      top : (_.random(0, 230)) + 'px',
      left: (_.random(0, 210)) + 'px'
    }
  }
},
```

How can I create an interval to run the calcPosition method every one second and animate the changes?

Comment: Is this what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/jc95vzgt/2/

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the method with a `setInterval()` and set a CSS transition property for the element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

You can initially call your method from your `mounted()` lifecycle state.